# SQL Most occurring months in descending order

Tags: sql, database, hive, hiveql

I have a column of dates in the following format: yyyy-mm-dd

How would I go about writing an SQL query to select the most occurring months in descending order?

I'm using Hive in Ambari

Comment: *Month* or *year/month*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT MONTH(dt_column) month_data, COUNT(*) month_count
    FROM table
    GROUP BY MONTH(dt_column);
    ORDER BY month_count DESC;
```

Comment: ordering by most occurring month according op question

Comment: Oops. Should order by count then

Comment: Btw, `count` is usually a keyword.

Comment: This answer worked. Was able to use it with count instead of month_count.

Comment: @Jason Well, great! It should work either way then :)

Comment: add `limit n` to the end of sql sentence to get top n months